# Bootstrap Grid within Kendo TabStrip

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, telerik, kendo-tabstrip

I want to use the Bootstrap Grid system to organise within Teleriks KendoUi TabStrip content. The first 2 rows shall use 10 column units, the third row has two elements with each 5 column units.
It seems two x 5 unit columns don't add up to the width of 10 units in the first two rows. It's working outside of TabStrip.
The Questions is: How do I fix the difference in behaviour?
Here is a sample: http://jsbin.com/xiherudoji/edit?html,output

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason lies in the box-sizing style, which is required to be border-box for Bootstrap, but is set to content-box by the kendo css. Overwriting the style for all elements within the TabStrip content div fixes the problem with Bootstrap and shows no negative effect on the TabStrip.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably because the col-sm-5 have their padding-left and padding-right. If you remove padding-right for third one, and padding left for fourth one, you'll see that the two align perfectly beneath the first and second.

Comment: Even if I remove the Labels itself, it does not change anything with the problem. If I check the dev tools it shows the padding responsible from col-sm-5 in bootstrap.min.css.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I was saying. My bad, I used labels. What I was trying to say is that the col-sm-5 has paddings, and thats whats making them to get our of the parent's widths.

Comment: The only difference is the style "box-sizing: content-box" within TabStrip by .k-widget and "box-sizing: border-box" outside the TabStrip by bootstrap. And thats it. I put .fix-box * {box-sizing: border-box;} in my css and everything is fine!